Jetpack Compose WebView with `rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData` back navigation
I have a WebView inside my Jetpack Compose data that I load with WebContent (HTML string) in this way:
val webViewState = rememberWebViewStateWithHTMLData(data = htmlString, encoding = "UTF-8", mimeType = "text/html")
WebView(
   modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
   state = webViewState,
)

This page might contain a link to a web url, which is handled fine as the WebView navigates to that URL.
Unfortunately, though, when navigating back (back gesture on the device), and returning to the initial page (loaded with HTML data), the page is not displayed correctly.
I tried using a WebViewClient, intercepting the URL being black/null/a special one (data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,), and re-loading the data myself, but it didn't work.
Any idea on how I could handle this specific scenario?
